# Program Crashes when I try to compare two strings in c++?

Tags: c++, string, function, crash, compare

```
int removeContact(Contact *newPtr, int runningTotal)
{
    //define variables
    string remove;
    int next;

    //prompt user for name they wish to remove
    cout << "Enter the name you would like to delete (Last name first): ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, remove);

    for (int t=0; t<=runningTotal; t++)
    {   
        if (remove.compare(newPtr[t].name) == 0)  
        {

            //calls function moveArrayElements function
            moveArrayElements(newPtr, runningTotal, t);

            //decrement runningTotal
            runningTotal--;

            //prompt user contact was found
            cout << "Contact was found and deleted!";

            next=1;
        }   

}

if(next!=1)
{
   cout<< "ERROR: Contact was not found!"; 
}

return runningTotal;
}
```

This function is apart of a larger c++ program that is designed to manage a persons contact information. This function is suppose to remove a contact.

The problem I'm have is with the `if (remove.compare(newPtr[t].name) == 0)` statement. When my program gets to this part of the code it will crash without giving any errors. I tried straight up comparing both the stings with `==` operator, but this still results in a crash of my program...

Also, what make this so strange is that this code works perfectly when the function is called while my program is running with the contact that I'm trying to remove not stored in a text file.

However, when I close my program, and load my contact information from the text file, my program will crash... I know that my program is reading the file into the proper string array because I have a print function, so I know that all of my contacts are being transferred into the proper structure arrays...

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

UPDATE: I took the suggestions in the comments and changed my for loop to

```
t<runningTotal;
```

However, when I do this my program doesn't crash, but it wont's compare the strings...

Comment: Could it be because of t<=runningTotal. Have you tried just <?

Comment: Are you sure about this `t<=runningTotal;`? Not just `t < runningTotal`?

Comment: Show us the file loading code and a small sample of the input file.

Answer (score 2):

If `runningTotal` is the size of your array, then the range of valid elements is `[0, runningTotal)`. In the below code, you're looping up to `runningTotal` *inclusive*, when there isn't a valid `Contact` object there:

```
for (int t=0; t<=runningTotal; t++)
{   
    if (remove.compare(newPtr[t].name) == 0)
```

Therefore when you go and dereference `newPtr[t]`, for `t = runningTotal` and then try and get the `name` element, you'll be causing undefined behaviour and may cause a crash.

Try changing `t<=runningTotal` to `t < runningTotal` to see if the problem goes away.

Also, is there a reason why you're using arrays as opposed to an `std::vector`?

Comment: @Edwin: haha, it's usually the other way around for me.

Comment: The reason I didn't use vectors is because I haven't learned them yet. I'll try your suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: @user1084680: oh ok. If you have the time, [take a look at them](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), they provide a lot of extra functionality and can save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @AusCBloke I tried you suggestion, and while my program doesn't crash, it just displays "ERROR: CONTACT WAS NOT FOUND." So something is still of, just don't know what...

Comment: @user1084680: check if the input didn't fail and check what the input was (debugger). Always (especially in C/C++) program defensively (anything can fail ,for whatever reason).

Comment: @user1084680: Try printing the name to be deleted at the start of the function, and print `newPtr[t].name` during each iteration of the loop to see what strings are actually being compared. You might not be taking in input properly.

Comment: @ AusCBloke: I just tried that, and both strings match up perfectly... I can's see why this wouldn't work...

Comment: @user1084680: Any newline characters at the end of any of the strings?

Comment: @ AusCBloke: I don't think so... Could you tell me how I can check that?

Comment: @user1084680: Actually, if you remove an element and move the other ones up, then you're going to be skipping an element. You should only increment `t` (`t++`) if you're not removing an element. Any chance you could post your full code if it's not too long?

Comment: I do that with my `moveArrayElements` function that I call in this function.

Comment: @user1084680: Remove `t++` from the `for` statement and move it to an `else` block so that `t` is only incremented if you remove an element. But that'll only happen if you actually find a conact... If you can provide the complete code and a sample input file, we should be able to find the problem.

Comment: @ AusCBloke: could I send you a message with it? It's it's over 300 lines.

Comment: @user1084680: It worked the first time I ran it, then every time after that it wasn't loading and printing the data properly. Your problem might be somewhere in the loading of the file, the remove function seems to work fine, apart from the loop counter being incremented even when an element is removed.

Another thing, a quick way to remove an element from an array is to swap the element to be removed with the last element, and then decrease the length by 1.

Unfortunately I don't have the time to find the bug in the code, but keep at it and use a debugger and you should find it.

Comment: AusCBloke: ok, thanks for taking a look at it! I'll keep on debugging and looking it over.

Answer (score 1):

i guess the for statement should be:

```
for (int t=0; t<runningTotal; t++)
```